# Can a differentiation in PHP MYSQL library version to server version be causing random PHP Access Violation errors

Tags: php, mysql, windows, pdo

My web application uses PDO to run queries and sporadically the site has been crashing with the following error:

> PHP has encountered an Access Violation at 01CBAD66

There seems to be no pattern to this, but I do see the following warning when logging into phpMyAdmin:

> Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.6.22. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

Can this be causing the issue? I am using PHP 5.2.16.

Comment: I would fix that, yes. What operating system are you on? How did you install PHP?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.16 - OS is Windows and PHP was not installed by me unfortunately so can't say.

Comment: Why not tell that person to upgrade your php? that PHP version was already EOL years ago, if you have  5.3 or > , you woudn't come across with that kind of problem, using that will have a security implications to your application.

Comment: Yep, sounds like a bug that may have been fixed in a later version. I don't use Windows, but I understand Microsoft and Zend have done a lot of good work together in recent years to make PHP more stable on this platform. Unless your software requires an unsupported version of PHP, upgrade to at least 5.4, and 5.6 if you can.